# List in struts form does not get updated

Tags: forms, list, struts-1

I have the following action form:

```
public class ImageGalleryActionForm extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {
    private String name;
    private List<GalleryImage> images; 
    //GalleryImage is just a class with name and description as strings (and get/set methods)
    public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<GalleryImage> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<GalleryImage> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public ImageGalleryActionForm() {
    this.name = "";
    this.images = new ArrayList<GalleryImage>();
}

@Override
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping,HttpServletRequest request){
    name = "";
    images = new ArrayList<GalleryImage>();
}
}
```

In an Action i preload some of the values for the *images* list, in the JSP i show these values and allow the user to change the descriptions of the images and the name of the gallery:

```
<html:form action="/pages/createNewGalleryAction" method="
    Gallery name: <html:text property="name" />
    <logic:iterate id="images" name="ImageGalleryActionForm" property="images">
         Image name: <bean:write name="images" property="name"/>
         Description:<br/>
         <html:textarea name="images" property="description" />
    </logic:iterate>
    <html:submit>Submit</html:submit>
</html:form>
```

This shows as expected, but when the next action receives the form it has only the ImageGalleryActionForm *name* set correctly. The list *images* is simply empty.

Where could the error lie?

Comment: Isn't there an `indexed` attribute or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find this sooner because different keywords were used.
The question is answered here: [Struts logic:iterate input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246684/struts-logiciterate-input-field)